# XPath to take textarea with specific value

Tags: xpath

I have got two textareas:

```
<textarea></textarea>
<textarea></textarea>
```

Some texts are written by hand when page loads. Lets say we will write "abc" to first and "cde" to second.

The question is simple:

How to get one, with specific text inside? In our case, lets say "cde"

Comment: post url or html code

Comment: I have posted the example. its just two textareas. In the final result, it will have more attributes and so on, but the only option to filter one of two - select by the needed text. Any options?